Is it legal in the US to name a business after a property in the public domain?
For example, if I were to name my LLC "Sherlock Holmes Enterprises LLC", would that be legal?

The copyright for the Sherlock Holmes stories has ended but that doesn't necessarily mean that the trademark isn't already held by someone.

It depends which products or services you intend to trade under that name. It's possible for the same mark (or similar marks) to be used by two different people for two different products if they're sufficiently distinct.

https://tmsearch.uspto.gov/search/ will answer your question: there are several "Sherlock Holmes" trademark.

There’s no public domain in trademark law
Conan-Doyle’s copyright in the Sherlock Holmes stories has expired but the phrase “Sherlock Holmes” is protected by a number of active trademarks.
As long as you don’t infringe those trademarks, that is, you don’t use it to promote goods and services in the protected classes, you’re fine.

Your link doesn't show any results.

@Barmar Does for me

Looks like the link is the result page but without underlying parameter, thus clicking the link will return 0 result. Readers need to do the search manually to see the result (which I got 32 as of current writing)

I suspect you had a query session open and it's using that saved information. There's nothing in the URL that specifies a Sherlock Holmes query. And if you query for something else, and click on the link again, you'll get those new results.
